# Why modal popup broke html bootstrapping

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-core

1. When i push button open popup window, but this window work not correctly. I cant fill all lines and page footer climbs on the window popup 
   [image]
   how fix it?
   i use only bootstrap and i dont see any z-index

i have PartialView but i think that is view broke

this is view

```
@{
    ViewData[index: "Title"] = "Create";
}

<h3>Create Employee</h3>
<hr/>
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="addEmployeeLabel">Add Employee</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form asp-action="Create">
                <input name="IsValid" type="hidden" value="@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid.ToString()"/>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="FistName"></label>
                    <input asp-for="FistName" class="form-control"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="FistName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="LastName"></label>
                    <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Position" class="control-label"></label>
                    @Html.DropDownList("PositionId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewData["PositionId"], "- Select -", new {id = "PositionId"})
                    <span asp-validation-for="Position" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Salary"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Salary" class="form-control"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Salary" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DateStart"></label>
                    <input asp-for="DateStart" class="form-control"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DateStart" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DateEnd"></label>
                    <input asp-for="DateEnd" class="form-control"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DateEnd" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-save="modal" id="save-employee">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

if need i can uploaded this progect to google disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its simple fix html bootstrapping. i transferred next code before `</form>`

````
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-save="modal" id="save-employee">Save</button>
        </div>```
````

Comment: No,in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60844193/11398810) you marked.It is because I add `Layout = null` instead of changing the location of the button.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you create a modal in a separate razor view,it would use `Layout` by default.

Add the following code to your bootstrap modal and no need to add html outside the modal:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@*<h3>Create Employee</h3>
<hr />*@
```